# Mysql query headache

Tags: mysql

So i've got a message table between users in my website.

```
id            from_user_id        to_user_id        content
 1             A                   B                 Hello, what's your name
 2             B                   A                 My name is B, what's your name
 3             A                   B                 My name is A
 4             C                   A                 Hello A, my name is C`
```

So, in my List message page of user A, i want to list it as below (For all messages from/to user A to/from user B, i just want to get the last message):

`Check all (checkbox)      User name              Message
                           B                      My name is A
                           C                      Hello A, my name is C`

I've tried something like this:

`SELECT * FROM message WHERE from_user_id = "A" OR to_user_id = "A" GROUP_BY to_user_id ORDER BY id`

But it will list 2 last messages from user A to user B and B to A:

-) My name is A

-) My name is B, what's your name

What is the way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select user_name, content
from message m,
(select max(id) as id, case when from_user_id='A' then to_user_id else from_user_id end as user_name from message where from_user_id='A' or to_user_id='A' group by user_name) a
where a.id = m.id
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks for your answer but you get it quite wrong, I want to list all latest messages from user A to B, C, D....For example A have messages with B, A have messages with C also, i just want to list a first message in each conversation between A - B and A - C. I think it's like facebook chat or viber... Hi, hope you understand it

Comment: Thank you. Will try it and let you know :D

Comment: Had to twist it a little bit but i started to learn about CASE WHEN sql. Thanks a lot ded

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM message WHERE from_user_id = "A" OR to_user_id = "A"